# How to get an array of records in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I execute an SQL query with php, this is the code:

```
$get_inspection_dates_query = "SELECT `date` 
                                            FROM `vehicles` INNER JOIN `inspection_dates` ON `plate` = `id_vehicle`
                                            WHERE `plate` = '$vehicle_plate'";
$result_set = $connection->query($get_inspection_dates_query);
$inspection_dates = $result_set->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

`inspection_dates` is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2012-01-01
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2013-01-01
    )

)
```

but I don't want this.
I simply want an array of records, without the columns (even because I select only one column, so I don't need to have an array inside the array), something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = 2012-01-01
    [1] = 2013-01-01
)
```

I know that I could reach something like this with a while loop and `fetch` (`$row = $result_set->fetch())`, but I think it's a bit tricky.
Is there any other method to obtain that array quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` instead of `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

```
$inspection_dates = $result_set->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: thank you, I think this is the simplest solution! :)

Comment: @Clyky But this also has to be rin in your own loop?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, I've simple changed `$inspection_dates = $result_set->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` with `$inspection_dates = $result_set->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` and it has given me exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

Simply get each result one at a time and place the date in the array like this

```
$get_inspection_dates_query = "SELECT `date` 
                               FROM `vehicles` INNER JOIN `inspection_dates` ON `plate` = `id_vehicle`
                               WHERE `plate` = '$vehicle_plate'";
$result_set = $connection->query($get_inspection_dates_query);

$inspection_dates = array();  // init an empty array
while ( $row = $result_set->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ) {
    $inspection_dates[] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: so aren't there any other ways to obtain this without a loop?

Comment: probably, but remember `$result_set->fetchAll()`  is a loop, its just being run behind the covers

Comment: you're sure, but I prefer to use the simplest solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

To change you `inspection_dates` to what you want you could use:

```
$whatYouWant = array_column($inspection_dates,0);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think Pablo's answers is simpler :)

Comment: Yes, it is simpler, but are you sure it does what you want? Nothing wrong with doing it that way though.

Comment: yes, I've tried it and it gives me exactly what I want.